# ASN.1 definitions for basic SNMP exchanges

Tags: snmp, asn.1, rfc

What online resource is the authority for the complete set of ASN.1 definitions for the SNMP data structures used to request and respond with information? I am interested in versions 2c and version 3.

In [RFC 3416 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416#section-3), I have found most of the definitions needed to use version 2c. However, the document has no mention of something that I have found on other resources referred to as the "snmpv2 message". For example, this shows up in the [SNMP Programmers Reference Wiki](http://wiki.treck.com/SNMP_Programmer%27s_Reference#SNMPv2c_Messages_and_PDU_Formats) and in the blog post [Simple? Network Management Protocol](http://www.rane.com/note161.html). It's the data structure that contains the community string, so it's role is essential, but I cannot find where the authoritative source (probably an RFC) with an ASN.1 definition.

Similarly, I cannot find any authoritative ASN.1 definitions of SNMPv3 data structures. I found an [ASN file in a github repo's test suite](https://github.com/tysonite/asn1-compiler/blob/dbb95123435c5e6c7174ee0232ee1836114f89a4/runtime/tests/snmpv3-example/snmpv3.asn), but I cannot find where this information was taken from.

I would appreciate any help locating these. I'm usually a pretty good Googler, but my usual strategies are not turning anything up beyond what I've already linked to.

Answer (score 2):

SNMP v3 message format is defined in RFC3412 page 19 as section 6 as ASN.1.

SNMP v2c reuses most of v1 message format, except defining new message body (PDU). I think that's why in RFC 3416 you don't see all details, because it only mentions the new PDU definitions for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to dig ASN.1 documents out of [SNMP RFCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol#RFC_references):

- [Base data types, RFC2578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-2)
- [SNMP v2c message, RFC3416](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416#section-3)
- [SNMP v3 message, RFC3412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3412#section-6)
- [SNMP v3 USM, RFC3414](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414#section-2.4)